# Which is the right way to handle imbalanced data in a regression problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, unbalanced-classes, weighted-regression, weighted-sampling

I'm working on a regression problem with imbalanced data, and I would like to know if I'm weighting the errors correctly. I'll try to illustrate the concept with a simple example.

Imagine I'm building a model to predict house prices in New York and Los Angeles. I have many more training examples in `NY` than in `LA`, but I want the algorithm to perform equally well in both cities. To further complicate the issue, house prices in `NY` have a greater variance than those in `LA`.

Here is an example training dataset:

```
City    N_rooms  House_Price
NY      4        400
NY      7        1000
NY      5        800
NY      3        300
NY      7        600
NY      2        100
NY      4        500
LA      3        400
LA      5        500
LA      4        500
```

I have `7` training examples for `NY` and `3` training examples for `LA`. If my cost function is `MSE`, namely `sum((y_pred - y_true)^2)/10`, to make sure that the algorithm performs equally well in both cities, I would need to give different weights on the prediction errors, namely

`sum(w * (y_pred - y_true)^2)/10`

I would like to know which one of the following would be the correct way to define `w` and/or rescale training data:

1. Do not use weights (i.e., `w=1`)
2. Define `w` as the inverse frequency of each class in the training set, namely `w=1/3` for houses in `LA` and `w=1/7` for houses in `NY`
3. Standardize prices in `NY` and `LA` separately, namely subtract the average price in `NY` from the price of every house in `NY`, then divide the price of every house in `NY` by the standard deviation of house prices in `NY`. Similarly, subtract the average price in `LA` from the price of every house in `LA`, then divide the price of every house in `LA` by the standard deviation of house prices in `LA`. Now train the regression model on the scaled data. To predict actual prices, apply the inverse scaling to the model predictions.
4. Apply both points `2` and `3`.

Note: the goal is not only to minimize the overall error, but to build an algorithm that performs equally well in both cities.

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood you correctly, the issue here is that you wish to fit your regression in such a way that it performs equally well on both cities, by which you means that you want to minimise the *weighted* sum-of-squares, with weights that ensure equal total weight to the data from each city.  If that is correct, then this should be  a fairly simple problem, where you can use [weighted least-squares estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares).  For this type of estimation, you have an $n \times n$ diagonal weighting matrix $\mathbf{w}$, and the coefficient estimator is:

$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{w} \mathbf{x})^{-1}
(\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{w} \mathbf{y}).$$

Now, suppose that you have $n_\text{NY}$ data points from New York and $n_\text{LA}$ data points from Los Angeles (so that $n= n_\text{NY}+n_\text{LA}$).  Then you would use weights $w_\text{NY} = 1/n_\text{NY}$ and $w_\text{LA} = 1/n_\text{LA}$ in your weighting matrix, and this would ensure that the two cities are equally weighted in the aggregate.  As a result of this weighting, more weight would be given to data points from the city that has been sampled less.

Now, I will also deal with your further complication, which is that you say there is more variance in one city than the other.  My suggestion here would be to fit a first-pass model where you use weighted-least-squares, with a weight of unity on one city, and a free parameter to weight the other city.  This will give you an estimate of the relative sizes of the error variance for the two cities.  You can then take that estimate and apply it as an additional weight when you do your main weighted analysis (as described above).  So, for example, if we let $\hat{\delta} \equiv \hat{\sigma}_\text{NY}^2 / \hat{\sigma}_\text{LA}^2$ denote the estimated relative error variance, then we would use the subsequent weightings $w_\text{NY} = 1/n_\text{NY}$ and $w_\text{LA} = \hat{\delta}/n_\text{LA}$ in your weighted analysis.  This should allow you to incorporate both the different error variance of the two cities, and also apply your own weighting to force the analysis to give "equal weight" (after adjustment for error variance) to the two cities.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but do you have any source for this approach? @Ben

Comment: @MetalMathematician: The general methods of weighted-least-squares estimations is presented in most texts on regression analysis and GLMs.  The specific approach of setting the weightings for groups to give equal total weight to those groups (when they have different amounts of data and potentially different variance) is not something I've seen discussed before, but it is one possible application of weighting in general.  I would not necessarily *recommend* undertaking this exercise in the first place, but if the OP really wants to do it, the weighting method would accomplish this.